# Deriving $A^{\mu}_{;\nu}$ from $A_{\mu ; \nu}$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, covariance

We have a covariant derivative of a covariant tensor:
$$
A_{\mu ; \nu} = A_{\mu , \nu} - \Gamma^{\alpha}_{\mu \nu} A_{\alpha}
$$
The covariant derivative of a contravariant tensor is:
$$
A^{\mu}_{;\nu} = A^{\mu}_{,\nu} + \Gamma^{\mu}_{\nu \alpha} A^{\alpha}
$$

I am trying to use $A^{\mu}_{;\nu} = (g^{\mu \sigma} A_{\sigma})_{;\nu}$ to derive the second equation, given the first.

My attempt is as follows:
$$
\begin{align}
A^{\mu}_{;\nu}
&= (g^{\mu \sigma} A_{\sigma})_{,\nu} - g^{\mu \sigma} \Gamma^{\alpha}_{\sigma \nu}A_{\alpha} \\
&= A^{\mu}_{,\nu} - \Gamma^{\mu \alpha}_{\nu}A_{\alpha} \\
&= A^{\mu}_{,\nu} - (g^{\alpha \epsilon}\Gamma^{\mu}_{\nu \epsilon})A_{\alpha} \\
&= A^{\mu}_{,\nu} - \Gamma^{\mu}_{\nu \epsilon}(g^{\alpha \epsilon}A_{\alpha}) \\
&= A^{\mu}_{,\nu} - \Gamma^{\mu}_{\nu \epsilon}A^{\epsilon}
\end{align}
$$
Relabelling $\epsilon$ as $\alpha$ we have:
$$
A^{\mu}_{;\nu}= A^{\mu}_{,\nu} - \Gamma^{\mu}_{\nu \alpha}A^{\alpha}
$$

Clearly there is an error in my method here, as I have a minus where I ought to have a plus. Have I missed a step, or am I going about this the completely wrong way?

Thanks, Sean.

Comment: Is the Christoffel symbol symmetric in the upper two indices?

Comment: This is the first that I've ever encountered a Christoffel with two up indices. I'm assuming that if it is antisymmetric in the upper indices, then the sign would change between my 2nd and 3rd line of working?

Comment: Covariant derivative of the metric tensor is exactly 0, so you can freely move it in or out the derivative expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explicitly working with the components of $g$ and $\Gamma$ can be messy.
Here is a nicer way to derive the coordinate expression for the covariant derivative of a vector (or any tensor) without raising or lowering indices.

Consider vector fields $A^\mu, B_\mu$.
The covariant derivative of a scalar is the same as the coordinate derivative (in any coordinate system), so
$$
\nabla_\nu(A^\mu B_\mu)=\partial_\nu(A^\mu B_\mu)=
(\partial_\nu A^\mu)B_\mu+A^\mu\partial_\nu B_\mu \ .
$$
On the other hand using Leibniz's rule for $\nabla$ and your expression for $\nabla_\nu B_\mu$
$$
\nabla_\nu(A^\mu B_\mu)=(\nabla_\nu A^\mu)B_\mu+A^\mu\nabla_\nu B_\mu
=(\nabla_\nu A^\mu)B_\mu+A^\mu\partial_\nu B_\mu-A^\mu \Gamma^\alpha_{\mu\nu}B_\alpha \ .
$$
Taking the difference of the two equations and relabelling the dumb indices in the Christoffel symbol term we obtain
$$
B_\mu(\partial_\nu A^\mu+ \Gamma^\mu_{\sigma\nu}A^\sigma-\nabla_\nu A^\mu)=0.
$$
Since this must be true for any one-form $B_\mu$ the term in brackets vanishes, and the components of the covariant derivative of a vector in some coordinates are given by

$$\nabla_\nu A^\mu=\partial_\nu A^\mu+ \Gamma^\mu_{\sigma\nu}A^\sigma \ ,$$

as you wanted to show. In a similar way you can now derive the coordinate expression for the covariant derivative of any higher order tensor.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\nabla_\mu A^\nu = g^{\nu\alpha} \nabla_\mu A_\alpha = g^{\nu\alpha} ( \partial_\mu A_\alpha - \Gamma^\lambda_{\mu\alpha} A_\lambda ) = g^{\nu\alpha} \partial_\mu ( g_{\alpha\beta} A^\beta ) - g^{\nu\alpha} \Gamma^\lambda_{\mu\alpha} g_{\lambda\beta} A^\beta 
$$
This simplifies to
$$
\nabla_\mu A^\nu  =   \partial_\mu A^\nu + ( g^{\nu\alpha} \partial_\mu g_{\alpha\beta}  - g^{\nu\alpha} \Gamma^\lambda_{\mu\alpha} g_{\lambda\beta} ) A^\beta 
$$
Finally, note that
$$
g^{\nu\alpha} \partial_\mu g_{\alpha\beta}  - g^{\nu\alpha}  g_{\lambda\beta}\Gamma^\lambda_{\mu\alpha} = g^{\nu\alpha} \partial_\mu g_{\alpha\beta}  - \frac{1}{2} g^{\nu\alpha}  g_{\lambda\beta} g^{\lambda \rho}  ( \partial_\mu g_{\rho\alpha} + \partial_\alpha g_{\rho\mu} - \partial_\rho g_{\mu\alpha} )  = g^{\nu\alpha} \partial_\mu g_{\alpha\beta}  - \frac{1}{2} g^{\nu\alpha}   ( \partial_\mu g_{\beta\alpha} + \partial_\alpha g_{\beta\mu} - \partial_\beta g_{\mu\alpha} ) =  \frac{1}{2} g^{\nu\alpha}   ( \partial_\mu g_{\beta\alpha} + \partial_\beta g_{\mu\alpha} - \partial_\alpha g_{\beta\mu} ) = \Gamma^\nu_{\mu\beta}
$$
Thus, we find
$$
\nabla_\mu A^\nu = \partial_\mu A^\nu + \Gamma^\nu_{\mu\beta} A^\beta
$$